# How to create QThread without task switching

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, c++14

I'm developing an Atmega328P MCU simulator and have a little problem regarding the timer. The timer in Atmega328P is ticking once per 62.5 ns (on 16MHz) and I have to simulate that. To solve problem I have created this class

```
class DLL_EXPORT Timer : public QThread
...

void Timer::run()
{
    CCPU* cpu = dynamic_cast<CCPU*>(parent());
    if (cpu == nullptr)
    {
        exit();
        return;
    }

    QElapsedTimer timer_core;
    timer_core.start();
    while (1)
    {
        if (timer_core.nsecsElapsed() >= 62)
        {
            ++cpu->GetIOPorts()[0x26];
            timer_core.restart();
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work fine, but there's a little problem regarding task switching process in CPU. How can I disable that process for this certain class?

Or maybe there is another approach for the solution?

Comment: Write a simple function that takes the current realtime value, subtracts the starting realtime value, and divides by 62.5 nanoseconds?

Comment: On task switching process it takes about 4-6ms (I think) that causes on timer problem. Timer ticks must be 62-63 ns.

Comment: Then simply put this logic into this function. Instead of using a restarting timer, like that, start a timer just once, and keep computing how many 62.5 ns intervals have elapsed, since it was started, instead of starting the timer every time, and thus accumulate errors over time. As long as the timer itself is stable, this will avoid introducing overhead.

Comment: The problem is not to calculate elapsed time. Problem is to run program in realtime. I mean not to have task switching processes, that can take 4-6ms. Problem is to avoid breaks

Comment: If you need multitasking, you cannot avoid the overhead of task switching. Because that's how it works. Either use a separate task, like this, or use the approach of simulating ticks by reading the current realtime, subtracting the starting point, and dividing by 62.5 ns. Those are your options.

Comment: Qt does not provide faculties to guarantee realtime timings in that range. If you need  accuracy that precise you will have to make a platform specific solution. What is the CPU/OS that you're targeting?

Comment: Intel Core i7 7820HQ Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: Well if just reducing the amount of times you miss the window is good then you should consider setting the priority of your process a little higher and then setting the priority of your thread to `SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), (1 << CoreNumber));` (where you set CoreNumber to something other than 0 or 1). If that's not enough I'm afraid only things like writing a kernel mode driver might guarantee even better results.

Comment: But in general I agree with Sam, unless you need to interact with outside systems it should be better to just look at the time and simulate multiple steps at once if you fall behind. Because a user won't notice timing differences on that level

Comment: OK. Thank you both for your assistance.